# Replacing more than x amount of new lines with 2 new lines

Tags: php, regex, newline

I am trying to replace *more than* 2 new line characters with 2 new line characters.

I currently have:

```
$text = preg_replace('/(\r\n|\n|\r){3,}/', "\n\n", $text)
```

Which works fine, however new lines aren't always going to be `\n` characters, so I was wondering if there was anyway I could replace it with the correct new lines characters?

Comment: Can't understand. Which newline aren't always `\n`? The one you find or the one you replace? Do yo uactually mean how to replace `\n` or `\r`, whichever you find more that twice?

Comment: @RohitJain I mean I don't know what newline character the server will use; it may be `\r\n`, it may be `\n` or it may be `\r`.

Comment: What if you have `\r\n\n\r` ... what are you going to replace it with?

Comment: @Jack Why would a server use different new line characters!?

Comment: @Brett Why shouldn't a server use different line endings? It's not the server that decides on this :)

Comment: Though I agree Rohit's answer below is superior, I do feel obliged to mention `PHP_EOL` which is a constant that contains the proper way to do a newline in the current environment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `back reference` to replace with exactly the same newline that was matched: -

```
$text = preg_replace('/(\r\n|\n|\r){3,}/', "$1$1", $text)
```

Now it would automatically replace with `\n\n`, if `\n` was matched 3 or more times. Same for the other two.

So, whatever newline character your server was using will be used as replacement.

---

One more thing is, your above regex may match different newlines in the single line and try to replace it.

For e.g.: - `\n\r\r\n` will be matched and replaced with `\r\n\r\n`. If you want to make sure that only the similar newline is to matched for e.g.: -  `\n\n\n`, and replaced with `\n\n`, then you would need to change your regex to: -

```
$text = preg_replace('/(\r\n|\n|\r)$1{2,}/', "$1$1", $text)
```

Now it will match only same consecutive newlines - `\n\n\n\n\n`, `\r\r\r\r\r`, or `\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n`. And replace with `2 occurrences` of whatever matched.

Comment: A question, will this match variations of new lines as Jack asked? Just want to be safe.

Comment: @Brett.. Yeah it will. I updated my post to add the correct Regex to use.